# IIS port 80 is not directing to my site

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iis

Im hosting a web service via IIS that I've set up bindings for on port 80, 81, 82, and 83. The hostname for each of the bindings is my registered domain.

Im not able to get port 80 to work. I've checked port scanners and it shows that port 80 is closed, but the others are open and I am able to access the site my adding the :port number to the url without an issue. The only port im having issues with is port 80.

I've forwarded all of these ports on my router as well so that the internal and external ports are the same.

I checked my ISP and they do not block port 80

I turned off all antivirus and firewalls on my server.

I'm using a Linksys EA6900 router.

Any other reason that port 80 isn't opening for me? I noticed that the ports don't show as "open" when scanning them unless I have the bindings set. In other words, if I forward port 83 on my router, it'll show as closed until I set the bindings for the IIS site to match that port.

Do I need to use a different hostname for binding port 80 maybe?

Comment: How do you configure the Linksys? CLI or WEB? if WEB, could it be Linksys is using port 80 for itselt?

Comment: You probably have an error in the port-forwarding of port 80 or in the IIS binding. Please add the relevant settings to your post.

Comment: Im not sure if Linksys uses port 80 for itself, but if I check the open ports of my external IP address or my domain, it shows that port 80 is closed.

Comment: For linksys settings, Im in Security > Applications and Gaming > Port Forwarding. Internal port is 80. External port is 80. IP address is the local IP address of my web server. Both TCP and UDP protocols are open on the router. In the IIS bindings, type is Http, Ip address is All Unassigned, host name is my domain name. port is 80

Comment: if i try accessing my site using the domain name and the port (mydomain.com:81) im able to see the site. If I specify a port other than the open ports on the router i.e. 85, the site immediately sends a "site unreachable" error, but If i dont specify a port or use port 80, it actually takes a bit longer to return the "site unreachable error"